# Can I override Gradle module's dependency with version built within the same multi-module project?

Tags: gradle

Imagine there is a Gradle project with 2 modules, `modA` and `modB`.  `modB` depends on `modA`.

```
// within modB's build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:modA:x.y.z'
}
```

I could also define the top level's project dependencies like this:

```
// within the top level build.gradle
project(':modB') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':modA')
    }
}
```

In this latter example, the output from `modA`'s compilation is put on the classpath for the compilation of `modB`.

What happens if I use both in the same project: what version of classes will get compiled into `modB`?  Will it be version `x.y.z` of `modA`, or will it be the versions that have just been compiled?

I'm trying to work out a sensible way of versioning a monorepo's submodules, where each submodule needs to have a separate version and I'm wanting to understand how Gradle resolves versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These notations are different:

1. First asks gradle to go to the repository (public or local, it depends on main gradle file) and get jar from there. In this case `mobB` and `mobA` are fully independent, so they could be built in parallel.
2. Second asks gradle to use local project. It means that `mobB` requires compilation of `mobA`, etc.

For complex multiproject, please also consider [Spring Dependency Management plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/). It allows you to define complex rules at the one include script. For example, you can put logice like this "if project is external client then exclude the following". As a result, you can consolidate all dependencies and versions at the one script, so your project will contain nothing.

Comment: Thanks, and for the link to that plugin, that's new to me!